# How do you loop over a tag field when passing from template to a custom template tag in Craft 3?

Tags: php, twig, craftcms

Supposing I have a Twig template like this:

```
{{ craft.myPlugin.bar(entry.specialTags) }}
```

How can I efficiently do the following within my custom template tag?

```
public function bar($tags)
{
    if ($tags->contains('blah')) { // pseudo-code!
        // return something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can loop through each of the tags of a tag field like this:

```
for ($tagField->all() as $tag) {
    if ($tag->title == "blah") {
        // return something...
    }
}
```

Or to use something like the following to convert into a list of just tag titles:

```
$tagTitles = array_map(
    function($tag) { return $tag->title; },
    $tagField->all()
);
```